# Creating a definition to overlay or more plt.plot() using definitions in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

For the life of me I can't figure this out, and I've been at it for a few hours now.  I would like to create a chart, that I can overlay multiple charts on. I've created a definition for the chart, but it doesn't return anything (I've tried to modify it to return an ax, but that doesn't work either). As it stands it outputs two seperate charts, perfectly the way I want it to work.  However, I'd like it to print 1 chart, with both lines overprinted. Here is where my code is at:

```
def plot_tera_wasserburg_concordia(lambda238=1.54*10**-10,
                   lambda235=9.72*10**-10,
                   show_ages=True,
                   title="Tera-Wasserburg Concordia Diagram",
                   linecolor="r"):
    df = get_ratio_data(lambda238, lambda235)   # I've defined this elsewhere 
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,16))
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.set_xlim([0,35])
    ax.set_ylim([0,0.62])
    plt.xlabel("238U/206Pb", fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel("207Pb/206Pb", fontsize=16)
    plt.title(title, fontsize=22)
    if show_ages == True:
        get_ages(lambda238, lambda235, 'tw') # I've defined this elsewhere
    plt.plot(df["ratio_238U_206Pb"], df["ratio_207Pb_206Pb"], linecolor, zorder=1)
    
geochron.plot_tera_wasserburg_concordia(show_ages=False)

lambda238=1.55125*10**-10
lambda235=9.8485*10**-10

geochron.plot_tera_wasserburg_concordia(lambda238,
                                        lambda235,
                                        show_ages=False,
                                        linecolor="g")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create the figure inside the function. So you create a **new** figure every time you call `plot_tera_wasserburg_concordia`. I suggest you move the common creation/ labels outside the function. That's from the `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,16))` line until the `plt.title(title, fontsize=22)` line. Then call the function twice, followed by `plt.show()`

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to move bits and pieces of that outside the function, but once I moved the whole thing it worked perfectly.  I figured it had something to do with that.  I was trying to pass in the figure as a parameter at one point.

Comment: You can do that, but I would suggest you pass the `ax` axis object instead.